# I want to use material icons instead of font awesome icons in vue-sidebar-menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

```
<template>
  <sidebar-menu :menu="menu" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        menu: [
          {
            header: 'Main Navigation',
            hiddenOnCollapse: true
          },
          {
            href: '/',
            title: 'Dashboard',
            icon: 'fa fa-user'
          },
          {
            href: '/charts',
            title: 'Charts',
            icon: 'fa fa-chart-area',
            child: [
              {
                href: '/charts/sublink',
                title: 'Sub Link'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I tried to add stylesheet link in the head of the inde.html. But nothing happens. I am using quasar cli to implement this vue-sidebar-menu.